# HTML/CSS How to make menu slide up when menu item is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, css-transitions

Like the title says, I have a sidebar menu that I'm trying to get to completely slide up and out of sight when one of the menu items, blog, is clicked. Similar to this jsfiddle I found (preferrably without js simply bc I hardly know it, but if that's the only way no big): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbatey/duZpT/)  ; except my menu is already open and you will be clicking an item inside the menu to slide it up. I'm trying to get the menu to slide up slowly.
The menu looks like this:

### Logo

- home
- blog
- instagram
- about
- store
- portfolio
- contact

Everything I try changes the whole layout of the sidebar, which I don't want. Here's some of my code:

```
<div id="sidebar"> 
        <div id="navigation">
          <div id="logo">
          <img src="Logos/headerlogo.jpg" width="208" height="80" longdesc="Logos/headerlogo.jpg">
        </div>
    <hr size=1 width=179 align=left style="margin-left:17px; margin-bottom:20px">
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="first" >
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Blog</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Instagram</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">About</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Store</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have some other code in there like a search bar, etc. but this is basically what I'm trying to get to roll up slowly when 'blog' is clicked. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this effect by using jQuery's `.animate` and animating the position of your elements. In your case, you could do something like this, using a margin to create the sliding up animation. Please note that I added a class called `blog` to the blog link.

```
$('.first .blog').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').animate({
        "marginTop": "-=500px"       //animate margin to create slide up animation  
    }, 1000);                        //duration of animation, in milliseconds
});
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ge5n4tx5/).

Comment: I can't get this to work in Dreamweaver or a browser. It works fine in jsfiddle, and I called it by doing this: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">

$('.first .blog').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').animate({
        "marginTop": "-=500px"       //animate margin to create slide up animation  
    }, 1000);                        //duration of animation, in milliseconds
});
</script>

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out. The correct formatting should be <script type="text/javascript"> /**same code**/ </script>. Without the src=ajax.googleapis...

Answer (score 1):

easy way to do it is use jquery, i think it impossible just with html and css, take a look with http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g4m2cf0a/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="navigation">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="208" height="80" longdesc="Logos/headerlogo.jpg">
        </div>
        <hr size=1 width=179 align=left style="margin-left:17px; margin-bottom:20px">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="first">
                    <li> <a href="#" title="" runat="server">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a class="blog" href="#" title="" runat="server">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" title="" runat="server">Instagram</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" title="" runat="server">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" title="" runat="server">Store</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" title="" runat="server">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" title="" runat="server">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".blog").on("click", function () {
    var slide = $(this).closest(".first");
    $(slide).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: I like this option, but for some reason none of the submenu items appear when I add that.

Comment: None of the <li>'s appear?

Comment: No those appear, but I have extra ul class items in between those (submenu of portfolio, for example) but I didn't post that part because I wanted to keep it short.

Comment: You mean they disappear when you click blog? If so, it's because your other menu also uses the "first" class and you can change it slightly. Better yet, use this for your top menu class="first close" then change the selector in the jquery to close instead of first.

Comment: No, they just don't appear when I click the submenus if the javascript is added.

Comment: Oh, I am not sure what would cause that because it should only affect the "first" class when you click the "blog" class.